# Как ровно расставить элементы над ползунком input range с учетом адаптивности

Tags: javascript, jquery, range

Есть такой инпут

```
<div class="rangeparent">
<input type="range" id="range" value="1" max="30" min="1">
</div>
```

шириной в процентах (80)
и элементы span которые нужно раставить над 10 и 26 изначально
пробовал делать вот так

```
var el = $('#range');
var w = el.width();

labels = [0,10,26]
for(i=1;i<=labels.length;i++){
var label = $('<span class="label"></span>');
var left = w/el.attr['max']*labels[i];
label .css('left',left +'px');
$('.rangeparent').append(label);
}
```

массив конечно для примера переделан, у элементов label позиционирование абсолютное, проблема в том что 10 ставится норм а 26 немного на растоянии, и при маленьких разрешениях 10 тоже неровно над нужным местом в инпут

Comment: Вам здесь поможет только кастомный `input type="range`

Comment: в смысле плагин качать?

Comment: В смысле самому делать плагин. Ну или искать готовый, в котором будет нужный вам функционал.

Comment: У Вас не учтены ширина span, ширина ползунка и то, что значения range начинаются не с нуля. Попробуйте 6 строку JS-кода переписать так: **var left = (w - w1) / (el.attr['max'] - el.attr['min']) * labels[i];** а 7 строку так: **label .css('left', (left - w2) +'px');**, где w1 - ширина ползунка, а w2 - ширина span